# Probability Theory: Likelihood Function definition question

Tags: probability, probability-theory, probability-distributions

I have question on whether the Wiki definition is correct.  Defined on [Wiki](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Likelihood_function#Discrete_probability_distribution) as:

a)
$$
\mathcal{L}(\theta \mid x) = p_\theta (x) = P_\theta (X=x)
$$
where $p_X$ is the probability mass function defined as:
$$
p_X(z) = P(X = z) = P(\{s \in \Omega : X(s) = z\})
$$

Then used as follows in an coin toss [example](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Likelihood_function#Example) on Wiki:

b)
$$
P(HH | P_H = \frac 1 2) = (\frac 1 2)^2
$$
$$
\mathcal{L}(P_H = \frac 1 2 | HH) = \frac 1 4
$$

Is the Wiki (a) definition correct?  I ask because $P_\theta(X = x)$ appears adding an extra parameter vs the PMF $p_\theta(x)$.  If it is correct, can someone explain why the RHS of (a)?

Answer (score 1):

$\theta$ is the parameter; $p_\theta(x)=P_\theta(X=x)$ are referring to the same probability with respect to/using the parameter $\theta$. $X$ is the random variable and its distribution is said to be indexed by parameter $\theta$.

So for the coin toss example $P_H=\frac 12$ is the parameter.

Comment: I have learned the PMF as $p_x(y)$ where $x$ is the random variable and $y$ is the value of the RV.  $p_\theta(x)$ appears to be using the subscript for the parameter value, rather then random variable.  Does that agree?  I see later on Wiki $P_\theta(X = x) = P(X = x; \theta)$ which agrees with the material I have seen.

Comment: @Nick Yes, I think those are all correct statements. The subscript is being overloaded in two meanings here.